# How to convert json to csv python with proper headers

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

Trying to get Json data to csv i am getting the values but one block is showing as one line in result, new to python so any help appriciated. Have tried the below code to do the same.

```
import pandas as pd

with open(r'C:\Users\anath\hard.json', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
    df = pd.read_json(inputfile)

    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\anath\csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=True)
```

Sample Json in the source file, short snippet

```
{
  "issues": [
    {
      "issueId": 110052,
      "revision": 84,
      "definitionId": "DNS1012",
      "subject": "urn:h:domain:fitestdea.com",
      "subjectDomain": "fitestdea.com",
      "title": "Nameserver name doesn\u0027t resolve to an IPv6 address",
      "category": "DNS",
      "severity": "low",
      "cause": "urn:h:domain:ns1.gname.net",
      "causeDomain": "ns1.gname.net",
      "open": true,
      "status": "active",
      "auto": true,
      "autoOpen": true,
      "createdOn": "2022-09-01T02:29:09.681451Z",
      "lastUpdated": "2022-11-23T02:26:28.785601Z",
      "lastChecked": "2022-11-23T02:26:28.785601Z",
      "lastConfirmed": "2022-11-23T02:26:28.785601Z",
      "details": "{}"
    },
    {
      "issueId": 77881,
      "revision": 106,
      "definitionId": "DNS2001",
      "subject": "urn:h:domain:origin-mx.stagetest.test.com.test.com",
      "subjectDomain": "origin-mx.stagetest.test.com.test.com",
      "title": "Dangling domain alias (CNAME)",
      "category": "DNS",
      "severity": "high",
      "cause": "urn:h:domain:origin-www.stagetest.test.com.test.com",
      "causeDomain": "origin-www.stagetest.test.com.test.com",
      "open": true,
      "status": "active",
      "auto": true,
      "autoOpen": true,
      "createdOn": "2022-08-10T09:34:36.929071Z",
      "lastUpdated": "2022-11-23T09:33:32.553663Z",
      "lastChecked": "2022-11-23T09:33:32.553663Z",
      "lastConfirmed": "2022-11-23T09:33:32.553663Z",
      "details": "{\"@type\": \"hardenize/com.hardenize.schemas.dns.DanglingProblem\", \"rrType\": \"CNAME\", \"rrDomain\": \"origin-mx.stagetest.test.com.test.com\", \"causeDomain\": \"origin-www.stagetest.test.com.test.com\", \"danglingType\": \"nxdomain\", \"rrEffectiveDomain\": \"origin-mx.stagetest.test.com.test.com\"}"
    }
    }
  ]
}
```

Output i am getting is as below was looking a way where could field name in header and values in a column or cell so far getting the entire record in 1 cell. Any way we can just get specific field only like title, severity or issueid not everything but only the feilds i need.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("your_file.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

df = pd.DataFrame(data["issues"])
print(df[["title", "severity", "issueId"]])
```

Prints:

```
                                                title severity  issueId
0  Nameserver name doesn't resolve to an IPv6 address      low   110052
1                       Dangling domain alias (CNAME)     high    77881
```

---

To save as CSV you can do:

```
df[["title", "severity", "issueId"]].to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(data["issues"])
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined. Did you mean: 'id'?, getting this error, sorry i am bit new to python

Comment: @user3754136 I mean `import pandas as pd`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this worked for me @Andrej Kesely thanks for the inputs. sharing as might help others.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open(r'C:\Users\anath\hard.json', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
    data = json.load(inputfile)


df = pd.DataFrame(data["issues"])
print(df[["title", "severity", "issueId"]])
df[["title", "severity", "issueId"]].to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```